# Not getting which param to Pass and where found StorageCredentials on azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have azure Http Trigger Function. I want to read from azure table storage. As per function below If I want to call I need these parameter. So need that credential. But I am confused how do I invoke with which param also where can I get it.

```cs
var httpClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(""),
                          new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("", ""));
```

Comment: Take a look. If you have any more concern please feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: You are most welcome and glad to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get your Azure storage credentials.

**You need following parameter:**

1. Your Storage Account URL
2. Your storage Account Name
3. Your Storage Key
4. Storage table Name

**Azure Portal Action:**

5. Go To Azure  Portal
6. Select `Storage accounts`
7. Click Your Expected Application
8. Select `Access keys`

See the screen shot for better understanding

[image]

**Your code snippet:**

```cs
   var httpClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri("AccountURL"),
                          new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("AccountName", "AccessKey"));
```

One tip: if you just point your mouse on function in hover it will show you required suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`Uri` will be the table endpoint of your storage account. For example, if your account name is `myaccount`, the URI will be `https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net`

`Storage credentials` will be the name of your account and account key respectively. This is something you can get from Azure Portal. For the storage account in question, simply go to the `Access Keys` section and get the information from there.

[image]

```
 var httpClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri("https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net"),
                      new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("myaccount", "account key"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly available in the **[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.table._cloud_table_client?view=azure-java-legacy)**,

storageURI can be obtained as follows, if you goto your account on azure portal, you should be able to get the accountName and the key,

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TableStorage:AccountName"),
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TableStorage:Key"));
var storageUri = new StorageUri(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TableStorage:Uri")));
var cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(storageUri, credentials);
```